# jquery css change removes some css file rules

Tags: jquery, html, css

I noticed if I change the css of an element using jquery, it removes some css rules already specified to the element.

For example,

```
.className, .className2, etc... { 
   background-color: black;
   color    : silver;
}

.className:hover, .className2:hover, etc... { 
   background-color: gray;
   color    : white;
}
```

Now, if the user clicks this element, I want it to permanently change the background to show it has been clicked, and if another sibling element has been click, it will lose its jQuery-set css rules and go back to the original css-specified rules (aka, it will lose its rgba background, and the "hover" rules will be added back)

```
highlightClicked : function (el) {
        el.css({
            "background-color" : "rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7)",
            "color" : "white"
            });
        $('#parentElement > span').each(function () {   
            $($(this)).not(el).css({
                "background-color" : "rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.0)",
                "color" : "gray"
            });
        });
    },
```

But the jquery .css seems to remove those original rules.

How can they be preserved?

Comment: think they're not removed, just overridden... have you checked in the element inspector if the style attributes are really removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than use `.css()` to change an elements styles, a more efficient way of doing this is to add/remove a class:

**HTML**

```
//add a universal class to target with jquery, my example is .target
<div class="target className">className</div>
<div class="target className2">className2</div>
```

CSS

```
.active, .active:hover{ //don't add .active:hover if you want an actual hover state
  background-color:red; //Whatever style you want
  color: #FFF; //Whatever style you want
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".target").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".target").removeClass("active"); //will add the class to the clicked element and remove it from anyothers
});
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qd8rg4t/2/)

**OR** if you want to change classes for an individual element, you could simply use `.toggleClass()` like so:

```
$(".target").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qd8rg4t/3/)

Comment: I've used this approach before too, typically for tabs. Simple and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

@jmore009's answer is probably the best approach, but to answer your question:  jQuery simply overrides the style sheet rules, as @webeno pointed out.  You can restore them by setting the css properties to a null string:

```
el.css({
        "background-color" : "",
        "color" : ""
      });
```

Example:  **http://jsfiddle.net/1ec10ncn/2/**